# Prefer WiFi over Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, ethernet, network-adapter

I want to use my Ethernet power line adapter in order to use Wake on Lan for my desktop PC.

However, once it has booted into Windows, I want it to use my WiFi by default, as the powerline adapters are very cheap, and they get about 6/6 Mb/s, compared to 60/6 Mb/s through wireless, which is what I pay for at my ISP.

I have configured the Adapters and Bindings configuration so that the WiFi is preferred, but it seems to have no effect.
You can even see I tried to completely disable all protocols for the Ethernet connection, but once again, even after a couple of reboots, it seems to ignore the settings.
[image]

Outside of that, it also doesn't seem to want to automatically connect to my WiFi hotspot once Windows has booted.

I have no clue what could be causing this, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Running on Windows 8 Pro X64, fully updated.

**EDIT**
The Ethernet being preferred over WiFi is now fixed. Used the [method suggested by EntropyWins](https://superuser.com/questions/573790/prefer-wifi-over-ethernet#comment701464_573790) in the comment to this question.
However, it still doesn't automatically connect with my hotspot, even though I did check the "Connect automatically" checkbox on the hotspot.

Comment: Did you disable automatic metric? See http://superuser.com/questions/364978/windows-7-set-default-network-connection

Comment: Why do you want it to "prefer" wifi? The only difference I can think of is that wifi will be slower. What's the point?

Comment: Terdon, I am using a powerline adapter for the WoL, I live in a very old house, and they are extremely cheap, get about 6 Mb/s down and up. My Wireless adapter is very strong, and I get 60 down, 6 up on it, which is exactly what I pay for ;)
I added this reason to the question now. I knew someone was going to ask.

Comment: Entropy, that solves my issue with it preffering Ethernet over Wi-Fi! Thanks. Now the only problem is that it doesn't automatically connect to my hotspot... Any ideas?